# Can you use contribution fields on event registrations?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, profile, contributions

we have an event - we have custom fields for contributions that we would like filled out when people register. CiviEvent will not allow me to select a profile with contribution fields. How can I ensure the contribution/event fee has associated contribution fields that I would like provided.

Comment: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/
Except in Search Results Profiles, you can combine Contact fields with fields from one and only one of the other record types: Activity, Participants, Contributions, and Membership.

As far as I know, you're going to struggle to do this on an event registration page. 

What type of extra fields/ details are you wanting to capture? Will this be for all events you run?

Comment: I think you will have to create another custom set used for Participants. Then you can select that set in events. But i do not think you can use the same set for Contributions and Events

Comment: Every contribution - even if part of an event registration - has custom fields attached to it. Those fields define information about that contribution and help to generate useful reports. @CraigAlmond

Comment: As Iowa Boy says, unless you can reconfigure those fields as participant data you won't get them to display in the event registration page.

If you're using drupal you may be able to configure a webform for event registration and expose your contribution custom fields in there. (Not used webforms in this way myself- so can't help further with that)